# pyqt QTableView removal of row results in Excpetion: Qt attempts to create header for removed row

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt

I use PyQt to write a custom implementation of QTableView and QAbstractItemModel. I want to create a button, that removes a row from TableModel by calling re-implemented `rowRemoved` event handler. For some reason, model  attempts to create the row's header for removed row, which causes a crash.

Here are the implementations of `removeRows`, `headerData` and `rowCount`. `self.alignment.sequences` is the list of data, each header is filled with `sequences.name`:

```
def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
    print "removeRows called"
    self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows -1)
    for i in range(int(rows)):
        self.alignment.sequences.pop(position)
    self.endRemoveRows()

def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
    if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        return QVariant(str(col))
    elif orientation == Qt.Vertical and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        try:
            return self.alignment.sequences[col].name
        except:
            print "Exception: no header with index %s" % col

def rowCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.alignment.sequences)
```

For some reason, my application crashes. Its execution results in exception, caught in `headerData`:

```
Exception: no header with index 16
```

GUI creates space for header, corresponding to removed row, but, obviously, fails to fill it.

Do you have any ideas, why Qt doesn't react to row removal appropriately? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from a quick look, it seems like you data storage and headers are from the same variable. So you might have removed a header from remove Row. If you keep them as separate variables then your data manipulation wont affect your headers at all.

Another thing to do is to get rid of the Try Except with a generic exception. That way you can see what kind of error you are getting.

```
try:
    return self.alignment.sequences[col].name
except (IndexError, AttributeError) as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: But I wanted to delete the whole row with its header. Naturally I don't want a header for non-existing row. But Qt's GUI, TreeView or something is trying to draw the non-existing row and calls `headerData` for 16th row, while `rowCount` should've decreased already. As for the exception - thanks, I'll fix that.

Comment: Then keep it the way you have it, but make a call to update the header before you return the value. It looks like the header data is getting called, but the info isn't there, probably an IndexError. Use the headerDataChanged signal after you remove the data, but before you return the value.

Comment: Ah, good spot, thank you. I'll try. Yes, that's `list index out of range`.

Comment: Hm, no, reference discourages use of `headerDataChanged`: `If you are changing the number of columns or rows you do not need to emit this signal, but use the begin/end functions (refer to the section on subclassing in the QAbstractItemModel class description for details)` - from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerDataChanged

Comment: Justin, thank you, I found the source of mistake. I was modifying self.alignment.sequences in GUI part of code, instead of making a copy of it and modifying the copy. Thanks!